# express.static is not making all files static

Tags: node.js, express

app.use('/p',  checkAuth.refresh,  express.static('/public/p'),  publicRoutes);

This is my route to home page. Even though all the files (assets,js,css,html) are in the /public/p, I can send all files except app.js and style.css

[image]

[image]

Any idea?

EDIT:
file directory, I only try to make /public/p static. While index.html
and all other files such as some svg or json can be sent with no problem, app.js and style.css respond with 404 error code.

---

--|server

--|--|app.js

--|--|public

--|--|--|assets

--|--|--|p

--|--|--|--|app.js

--|--|--|--|index.html

--|--|--|--|style.css

Comment: Please show the folder structure and the full urls you are trying. Highlight the ones which work and the ones which doesn't.

Comment: added the file directory

Comment: But not the full urls i asked for. Hover over the style.css in the devtools to see the url the browser is trying to load. Can you also show the html with the script tag for app.js? Is it relative or absolute path?